# Dissolving ability of octane vs nonane on neoprene

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents

I have been working with straight chain octane and nonane. The neoprene seals in some parts of the apparatus are allegedly far more vulnerable to the deleterious effects of octane than nonane - why? [I assume it's a solvent thing]

Comment: Which isomers of octane and nonane are you using? I'd expect the effect will depend on that.

Comment: No isomers, just the single chain

Comment: @DirkBruere That's still an isomer.

Comment: The difference between singular and plural - you said "isomers"

Comment: I can see someone else edited the question - could you please confirm you're asking about n-octane and n-nonane? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - nice straight carbons lined up in a row

Comment: Very interesting. Is there any documentation on this effect or have you done any tests yourself?

Comment: Using this guide: http://mykin.com/rubber-chemical-resistance-chart-4